# digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt

Tags: python, encryption, openssl, popen

I'm trying to make a Python program that runs OpenSSL commands for the encryption and decryption of files.

In the command line I made:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ openssl enc -aes256 -base64 -k $(base64 alice_shared_secret.bin) -e -in plain.txt -out cipher.txt
vagrant@vagrant:~$ openssl enc -aes256 -base64 -k $(base64 bob_shared_secret.bin) -d -in cipher.txt -out plain_again.txt
```

And it works.
However, if I cipher the text with my Python program, I can't decrypt.

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ openssl enc -aes256 -base64 -k $(base64 bob_shared_secret.bin) -d -in cipher.txt -out plain_again.txt
bad decrypt
140321401345688:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:529:
```

What is the difference between my program and the cipher of the command line?

Code:

```
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python
openssl         = '/usr/bin/openssl'
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

def encrypt():
  arguments = [
    openssl,
    'enc',
    '-aes256',
    '-base64',
    '-k',
    '$(base64 alice_shared_secret.bin)',
    '-e', 
    '-in',
    'plain.txt',
    '-out',
    'cipher.txt',
  ]

  execute = Popen(arguments, stdout=PIPE)
  out, err = execute.communicate()

encrypt()
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't use shell string interpolation from the Popen parameters (your "$(...)" expression). Try encoding the base64 data directly and it will work fine:

```
import base64

with open('secret.bin') as x: secret = x.read()

def encrypt():
  arguments = [
    openssl,
    'enc',
    '-aes256',
    '-base64',
    '-k',
    base64.b64encode(secret),
    '-e', 
    '-in',
    'plain.txt',
    '-out',
    'cipher.txt',
  ]
```

Comment: Yeah! That's it! I didn't knew that can't use shell string interpolation from the Popen parameters. Thank you so much!

Comment: `python3 -c "from subprocess import Popen, PIPE;print(Popen(['echo', '$(dirname ${HOME})'], stdout=PIPE).communicate())"`